# How do you organize files that are being echo'd from a directory?

Tags: php, file, list, directory, reorganize

I have this code set to display files in a directory if they're songs. They get put into a list that doesn't organize in any order. I want to organize these songs by their file name. If I look into my FileZilla they files are organized by the name of the file just fine.

example:

- 01 - Song Title
- 02 - Song Title
- 03 - Song Title

*The songs aren't saved in any database. I've tried putting the songs into an array and using sort() but that only outputs the word "Array" over and over. I may be doing it wrong.*

you can see an example here how they get posted randomly: http://mixtapemonkey.com/mixtape?m=637

```
<?php
    $mixtapeid = $_GET['m'];
    $tb_name="mixtapes";

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tb_name WHERE id='$mixtapeid'") or die(mysql_error());
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($data);

    if ($handle = opendir("mixtapes/zip/".$info['id'])) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id'] && $entry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']) {   
                $item = "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry."/";

                    if ($newhandle = opendir("mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry)) {
                        while (false !== ($newentry = readdir($newhandle))) {
                            if ($newentry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry && $newentry != "mixtapes/zip/".$info['id']."/".$entry) {

                               $ext = substr($newentry, strrpos($newentry, '.') + 1);
                               if ($ext == "mp3" || $ext == "m4a")
                               {
                                    echo    "<li><a href='$item$newentry'>".basename($newentry, '.mp3')."</a></li>";
                               }
                            }
                        }
                        closedir($newhandle);
                    }

            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add the songs to an array and then call the `sort()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function.

change

```
if ($ext == "mp3" || $ext == "m4a")
{
    echo    "<li><a href='$item$newentry'>".basename($newentry, '.mp3')."</a></li>";
}
```

to

```
if ($ext == "mp3" || $ext == "m4a")
{
    $musicarray[] = basename($newentry, '.mp3');
}
```

then later in your code, you can sort this mucis array

`sort($musicarray);`

if you get an error about the array not being defined, you might need to add

`$musicarray = Array();`

somewhere earlier in your code.

This will only create the array and not display it. To print the array, after your giant loop you will need to echo out evrey key from the array, something like

```
foreach ($musicarray as $item)
    echo $item;
```

or equivalent

This is untested so it might need some fiddling to get working just right.

Comment: for some reason it wasn't going into an array(). It would list all the songs but they all came out with a key of 0. I'm not sure if I was doing it properly.

Comment: The code I have posted is all I have at the moment. How do I turn `$newentry` in an array and sort that array?

Comment: oh sweet deal. it works! I had to change `item` to `song` for the foreach echo, but yeah after minor adjustments it worked! Thank you very much!! All my users will love this.